# install specific version nginx 1.8.1

Tags: 14.04, server, nginx

How to  install specific version nginx 1.8.1

I have nginx 1.10.1 with homestead.
How i can install specific version nginx 1.8.1?

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.